# PHP form updates empty values

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to change the password using php form. If I leave the password field empty and still click submit, it updates the password to empty value.

```
// define variables and set to empty values
$mypassword = $passwordErr = $fid = $fidErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

if(empty($_POST["fid"]))
{
    $fidErr="ID is required";
}
else
{
    $fid=test_input($_POST["fid"]);
}

if(empty($_POST["mypassword"]))
{
    $passwordErr="Password is required";
}
else
{
    $mypassword=test_input($_POST["mypassword"]);
}

}
else
{
echo "plz enter details";
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<body>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p> 

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">

<br>Change password<br>

ID:
<input type="number" name="fid" value="<?php echo $fid; ?>">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $fidErr ?></span>
 <br>
Password:
<input type="password" name="mypassword" value="<?php echo $mypassword; ?>">
<span class="error">*<?php echo $passwordErr ?></span>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $fid;
echo "<br>";
echo $mypassword;


$sql = "update faculty set passwd='$mypassword' where fid=$fid";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

if($result==TRUE)
{

    echo "<br> $fid password updated successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "error".$conn->error();
}
```

Even though I have have put form validation code, it still updates the value to empty.

Comment: you always `update` it, even when your inputs are empty.

Comment: why you wrote code below, write update code in the success condition

Comment: authentication system *really* i mean *really* are not system that you should develop from scratch. Use a tried and tested one

Comment: put the update query inside an if statement which checks whether its empty or not

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to ignore the Password value if it is empty. Try this piece of code:

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $fid;
echo "<br>";
echo $mypassword;

if (empty($passwordErr)) {
    $sql = "update faculty set passwd='$mypassword' where fid=$fid";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);

    if($result==TRUE)
    {
        echo "<br> $fid password updated successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error".$conn->error();
    }
} else {
    echo "The password is not saved because it is empty."
}
```

UPD: changed the condition so it relies on $passwordErr value. Now the password emptiness check is not duplicated.

Comment: Thanks. But what does this statement do then?

Comment: if(empty($_POST["mypassword"]))//this one
{
    $passwordErr="Password is required";
}

Comment: I have just updated my answer. You are right, the condition you mentioned already does the check. BTW, if you try to save zero or a set of zeros as your password, the code won't work as expected.